# QTableView event filter not detecting some mouse events

Tags: c++, qt, events, qtableview

I installed a custom event filter to a TableView :

```
ui->groupBox->getView()->installEventFilter(mEventHandler.get());
```

and here is (part of) the eventFilter implementation :

```
bool EventHandler::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip)
    {
        return handleTooltipEvent(watched, event);
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        return handleMouseClickEvent(watched, event);
    }
    ...

}
```

But the MouseEvents never arrive at the eventFilter. I did a step by step debug, all types of events come through here but no mouse related event. When I click, the events arriving here are `QEvent::InputMethodQuery` events.

If I, instead, override the mousePressEvent() function of my table view, the events arrive there :

```
void CustomTableView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    auto proxyModel = dynamic_cast<QSortFilterProxyModel*>(model());
    if (proxyModel)
    {
       ...
    }
    QAbstractItemView::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

The [official Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#eventFilter) doesn't state any limitation / exclusion of MouseEvents from the eventFilter mechanism.

What I am missing? Can someone explain why aren't MouseEvents arriving at the eventFilter() method?

I can implement what I want overriding `QTableView::mousePressEvent()`, but that's not my preferred solution and I would like to understand what is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the event filter to table view's `viewport()`.

```
ui->groupBox->getView()->viewport()->installEventFilter(mEventHandler.get());
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I am missing? Can someone explain why aren't MouseEvents arriving at the `eventFilter()` method?

`QTableView` inherits `QAbstractScrollArea`, so it's like 2 widgets in one, the container, and the `viewport`.

By default, the `viewport` covers the whole container, making it inaccessible to mouse presses, here's a demonstration where I set the `viewport`'s background to blue, and did not modify `QTableWidget`:

[image: Viewport covering container]

From this, one can figure out why the event filter installed on `QTableWidget` registered no mouse press events.

If you squeeze the `viewport` (e.g., by setting a maximum size smaller than `QTableWidget` size), so that it does not cover the whole container, the event filter will register mouse press events on `QTableWidget`, because now it's **accessible**, and **is being clicked**.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Squeezed viewport]